# Check value in array exists Flutter dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to check condition

```
if (value in List) {
  exist
} else { 
  not exist
}
```

but nothing to help anyone having an idea then please share.

```
My List = _quantityController[];
```

itemId is integer

i want to check my item id exists in my list array or not...Thanks!

Comment: What kind of element do you have in you list ? can you update your question with more context ?

Comment: I have list like 
List<int> _itemController = [16,18];

int itemId = 16;

I want to check itemId exists in _quantityController or not?

Answer (score 275, accepted):

```
list.contains(x);
```

[Contains method](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Iterable/contains.html)

Comment: Perfect and powerful method. Also works on detecting subStrings.

Answer (score 47):

Above are the correct answers to the current question. But if someone like me is here to check value inside List of Class object then here is the answer.

```
class DownloadedFile {
 String Url;
 String location;
}
```

List of DownloadedFile

```
List<DownloadedFile> listOfDownloadedFile = List();
listOfDownloadedFile.add(...);
```

Now check if a specific value is inside this list

```
var contain = listOfDownloadedFile.where((element) => element.Url == "your URL link");
if (contain.isEmpty)
   //value not exists
else
  //value exists
```

There maybe better way/approach. If someone know, then let me know. :)

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for.It works. Thanks Abdullah!

Comment: The contains should work, however I don't know why it was not working for me where my list is a list of objects.  This method worked for me, many thanks.

Comment: if it exists returns the whole object. Can we just get the one we were looking for?

Comment: This saved me, thank you!

Answer (score 32):

**Checking array of class objects**

Better than Abdullah Khan's approach is to use **any** instead of **where** because where makes the array to be scanned completely. Any stops when it finds one.

```
class DownloadedFile {
 String Url;
 String location;
}

List<DownloadedFile> files = [];
bool exists = files.any((file) => file.Url == "<some_url>");
```

Comment: never know this exist , thanks !

Answer (score 24):

```
List<int> values = [1, 2, 3, 4];
values.contains(1); // true
values.contains(99); // false
```

Method - [Contains](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Iterable/contains.html) of [Iterable](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Iterable-class.html) does exactly what you need. See the example above.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using custom class then make sure to override `==()` method, so that dart can compare two objects.

Use this to check if a data is inside list:

```dart
mylist.contains(data)
```

Answer (score 7):

This was my case
I have a list like this
and I was looking for specific UUID within the List

```
 // UUID that I am looking for
 String lookingForUUID = "111111-9084-4869-b9ac-b28f705ea53b"


 // my list of comments
 "comments": [
            {
                "uuid": "111111-9084-4869-b9ac-b28f705ea53b",
                "comment": "comment"
            },
            {
                "uuid": "222222-9084-4869-b9ac-b28f705ea53b",
                "comment": "like"
            }
 ]
```

And this is how I iterate within the list

```
// This is how I iterate
var contain = someDataModel.comments.where((element) => element['uuid'] == lookingForUUID);
      if (contain.isEmpty){
        _isILike = false;
      } else {
        _isILike = true;
      }
```

That way I get the lookingForUUID in

Hope will help for someone

Answer (score 5):

Here's a complete example

```
void main() {
  List<String> fruits = <String>['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango'];

  bool isPresent(String fruitName) {
    return fruits.contains(fruitName);
  }

  print(isPresent('Apple')); // true
  print(isPresent('Orange')); // false
}
```

Comment: What do you get when your answer only uses existing answers content? You won't get votes if you simply refactor a code.

Answer (score 4):

To check if a particular element in the Map contains a particular value:

```
if (myMap.any((item) => item.myKeyName == whatever)) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution other answers didn't mention: [`indexOf`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-core/List/indexOf.html).

```dart
List<int> values = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
print(values.indexOf(5) >= 0); // true, 5 is in values
print(values.indexOf(1) >= 0); // false, 1 is not in values
```

It also lets you search after an index. With `contains`, one would do:

```dart
print(values.sublist(3).contains(6)); // true, 6 is after index 3 in values
print(values.sublist(3).contains(2)); // false, 2 is not after index 3 in values
```

With `indexOf`:

```dart
print(values.indexOf(6, 3) >= 0); // true, 6 is after index 3 in values
print(values.indexOf(2, 3) >= 0); // false, 2 is not after index 3 in values
```

Answer (score -3):

```
List<int> list1 = [1, 2, 2, 3];
List<int> list2 = [3, 2, 2, 1];

bool isEqual = list1.toSet().containsAll(list2) && list2.toSet().containsAll(list1);
print(isEqual);
```

This should show true.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: The question is about a single value and an array or list. Your post is about two lists and does not seem to answer *this* question.