# Is there an "in" operator in dart like in python or an equivalent

Tags: python, dart

Is there an "in" operator in dart like in python or an equivalent ,
An example or a link would really help.

I am trying to reduce the multiple testing of this if statement, since it is testing against the same value.

```
int value = 3
if(value == 3 || value == 2 || value == 5)
{
    do Something()

}
```

To something like this, however this is the syntax in python

```
if(value in (1,3,5))
do Something()
```

I would like to achieve this in dart.

Comment: It’s better to describe the problem you want to solve than the solution to that problem in another language (the Python `in` operator can accomplish a few different things).

Comment: in for iteration or in to check if something exists in a string or list?

Comment: @Ry . Thanks for tip, I have reformatted and added what I want to solve

Comment: using Google I found [contains](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Iterable/contains.html) for list and [Check value in array exists Flutter dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369340/check-value-in-array-exists-flutter-dart). And [contains](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.3/dart-core/String/contains.html) for string. Maybe you should also use Google.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check value in array exists Flutter dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369340/check-value-in-array-exists-flutter-dart)

Comment: @Jot I have added the code I was trying to reformat. Thanks.

Comment: @furas and Anthony, thanks for tip, I checked the contains keyword, it works with List, I will try if it works without a list value. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
  int value = 3;
  if([1,2,3].contains(value)){
    doSomething();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this solve my problem.

Comment: You are welcome @hTony. Accept?

Comment: You could put a `const` in front of the list to make it a compile-time constant.